# Mina and Websocket

Tags: java, google-chrome, websocket, web, apache-mina

I am looking for a good websocket implementation that support draft10.
I am already implementing Mina server in my app but I didn't see any reference to websocket support and draft10 in specific.

Its will be funny to find out that Mina isn't supporting the latest standards, where can I find any references to this?

Comment: You are for one. Is someone else against one? What is your actual question?

Comment: Websockets support TCP. Apache MINA supports TCP. What are you arguing against?

Comment: How do I implement websockets with Mina?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the plans and intentions of the Apache Mina project, send email to the Apache Mina users list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd written a MINA codec which will handle websockets for you.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRMINA-907

Its being used by other developers in the community too.